# Change loop for for stream

Tags: android, java-stream

I was wonder how can I change for:

```
 for (UserIndex.CoachingArea coachingArea : userIndex.coachingAreas){
            for (UserIndex.CoachingWeekRef coachingWeekRef : coachingArea.weeks){
                if (coachingWeekRef.trackingDays != null){
                    for (UserIndex.TrackingDay trackingDay : coachingWeekRef.trackingDays)
                        if (!trackingDay.status.equals(TrackingStatusEnum.WAITING.toString())) {
                            trackingDataStore.saveFirstCheck(false);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

on stream.
This is what I got:

```
 Stream.of(userIndex.coachingAreas)
                .forEach(coachingArea -> Stream.of(coachingArea.weeks)
                        .filter(coachingWeekRef -> coachingWeekRef.trackingDays != null)
                        .forEach(coachingWeekRef -> Stream.of(coachingWeekRef.trackingDays)
                        .filter(trackingDay -> !trackingDay.status.equals(TrackingStatusEnum.WAITING.toString()))
                        )
                );
```

how call last method to save data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another forEach. But this time, make the lambda a statement, rather than an expression (put braces around it).

```
final TrackingDataStore tds = trackingDataStore; // or whatever type it is
final String WAITING = TrackingStatusEnum.WAITING.toString();
Stream.of(userIndex.coachingAreas)
      .forEach(coachingArea -> Stream.of(coachingArea.weeks)
              .filter(coachingWeekRef -> coachingWeekRef.trackingDays != null)
              .forEach(coachingWeekRef -> Stream.of(coachingWeekRef.trackingDays)
                      .filter(trackingDay -> !trackingDay.status.equals(WAITING))
                      .forEach(trackingDay -> { tds.saveFirstCheck(false); }) // <-- here
                      )
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Stream.of(userIndex.coachingAreas)
 .flatMap(coachingArea -> Stream.of(coachingArea.weeks))
 .filter(coachingWeekRef -> coachingWeekRef.trackingDays != null)
 .flatMap(coachingWeekRef -> Stream.of(coachingWeekRef.trackingDays))
 .filter(trackingDay -> !trackingDay.status.equals(TrackingStatusEnum.WAITING.toString()))
 .forEach(trackingDay -> trackingDataStore.saveFirstCheck(false));
```

This assumes there are more than one `trackingDay` for which you want to call `trackingDataStore.saveFirstCheck(false)`.

If you only want to call `trackingDataStore.saveFirstCheck(false)` once (in case all filters have passed), you could use [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--):

```
Stream.of(userIndex.coachingAreas)
 .flatMap(coachingArea -> Stream.of(coachingArea.weeks))
 .filter(coachingWeekRef -> coachingWeekRef.trackingDays != null)
 .flatMap(coachingWeekRef -> Stream.of(coachingWeekRef.trackingDays))
 .filter(trackingDay -> !trackingDay.status.equals(TrackingStatusEnum.WAITING.toString()))
 .findAny()
 .ifPresent(trackingDay -> trackingDataStore.saveFirstCheck(false));
```